# user input and reading file contents

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

For full disclosure this is an assignment for my programming class and I just want tips or advice on some of the code.

Assignment details just for background information purposes.

Write a program that will read a number 1-100 from the user, and the name of a data file, and will tell the user what word is in the file and how many times the numbers shows up in the data file. Validate input number (keep asking until valid) and validate the file was successfully open.

text file contents: Darling 10 20 21 19 20

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>  // Needed for exit()
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    string fileName;
    int value;

    cout << "Enter the file name: ";
    getline(cin, fileName);

    // Open the file
    inputFile.open(fileName.c_str());

    // Check for successful opening
    if(inputFile.fail())
    {
       cerr << "Error Opening File" << endl;
       exit(1);
    }

    cout << "\nThe file has been successfully opened for reading.\n";

    cout << "Pick a number between 1 through 100. ";
    cin >> value;

    if (value >= 1 && value <= 100)
    {
     cout << value << " is in the acceptable range.\n";
    }
    else
    {
     cout << "Please enter a number from 1 to 100. ";
     cin >> value;
    }

    string word;
    int number;
    int count = 0;

    infile >> number;

    // Read a file until you've reached the end
    while (!inputFile.eof())
    {
        if (number == x)
        {
            sum1++
        }
        infile >> number;
    }
    cout << sum1;

    while (!inputFile.eof())
    {
       inputFile >> word;
        if (word == "input")
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    // Close the file
    inputFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated since I'm lost when it comes to the fstream portion of this assignment right now.

Thanks in advance,

James

Comment: This question may fit better at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: some info on streams: http://gehrcke.de/2011/06/reading-files-in-c-using-ifstream-dealing-correctly-with-badbit-failbit-eofbit-and-perror/